# What linear-algebra operation produces this vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Define an $N\times N$ matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & &  &   \\
a_{21} & a_{22}  &  &    \\
\vdots &  &  \ddots &   \\
 a_{N1} & \dots &  &  a_{NN}   
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and a vector
$$
x = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
\vdots \\
x_{N}   
\end{bmatrix}
$$
What is the simplest operation that produces the following vector:
$$
v = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}x_{1} \\
a_{21}x_2 + a_{22}x_2 \\
a_{31}x_3 + a_{32}x_3 + a_{33}x_3 \\
\vdots\\
a_{N1}x_N + \dots + a_{NN}x_N  
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I.e. each row in this vector is the dot product between row $j$ in $A$ and a vector filled with $x_j$.

This is clearly not the product $A x$. I have looked at elementary matrix multiplication and it does not seem like there is a simple operation in terms of that. One way to actually achieve it is split $A$ into $N$ matrices with each of the rows of $A$, then defining $N$ vectors filled with $x_1, x_2$ respectively etc, and then doing products and adding all the resulting vectors. Clearly, that seems like an overly complicated solution.

Have I missed something simple?

Comment: "This is clearly not the product Ax" ?? How so ?

Comment: It is clearly the product $Ax$.

Comment: @Calle: In the product $Ax$ the second component is $a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2$ and so one for the other components.

Comment: Oh boy, did I mess up reading this. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & &  &   \\
a_{21} & a_{22}  &  &    \\
\vdots &  &  \ddots &   \\
 a_{N1} & \dots &  &  a_{NN}   
\end{bmatrix}
$$

the matrix of the operator you are looking for is

$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & &  &   \\
0 & a_{21} + a_{22}  &  &    \\
\vdots &  &  \ddots &   \\
0 & \dots &  &  \sum_{j=1}^N a_{Nj}   
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand $a$ is a trinagular matrix, so you can define the matrix $D(A)$ as a diagonal matrix with the diagonal element $d_{ii}=\sum_j a_{ij}$ and the request vector is $D(A)x$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the matrix $\bf A$ has all 0s on it's strictly upper triangular part, a way to build the matrix bharb proposes is to do "$\textrm{diag}(\bf A 1)$" where 1 is the column vector filled with ones of such a size that the product is defined.